# How to I replace these two buttons with a text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I have these two buttons ACCEPT/DECLINE friend request

How do I replace them with the text "You accepted X's friend request" if you click the Accept button and with the "You declined X's friend request" if you click on the Decline button? I know I should add an eventlistener to it.

```js
const acceptRequest = document.getElementById('accept');
const declineRequest = document.getElementById('decline');
const actionsRequest = document.getElementsByClassName('action')

acceptRequest.addEventListener('click', () => {
  actionsRequest.style.display = 'none';
  this.value = 'X accepted your request';
})
```

```html
<div class="request">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="profile-photo">
      <img src="Content/request1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Hajia Bintu</h5>
      <p class="text-muted">8 mutual friends</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="accept">Accept</button>
    <button class="btn" id="decline">Decline</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you attempted [with adding an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the buttons? You should add your attempt to the question as a [mcve].

Comment: *"I know I should add an eventlistener to it."* - That sounds like a reasonable place to start.  So where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've edited my initial post

Comment: Do you want to just replace the button text, or replace the entire button with a new element like `<p>` that contains the message?

Comment: @Andrei-CătălinPostolache: Your code is producing an error on the browser console, have you noticed and researched that?  `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element.  It has no `style` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        let accept = document.getElementById("accept");
        let decline = document.getElementById("decline");
        let name = document.getElementById("friend").innerHTML;

        accept.onclick = () => {
            accept.innerHTML = "You accept " + name + " friend request";
            decline.innerHTML = "Decline";
        }

        decline.onclick = () => {
            decline.innerHTML = "You decline " + name + " friend request";
            accept.innerHTML = "Accept";
        }
```

```html
    <div class="request">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="profile-photo">
                <img src="Content/request1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h5 id="friend">Hajia Bintu</h5>
                <p class="text-muted">8 mutual friends</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="accept">Accept</button>
            <button class="btn" id="decline">Decline</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want but I think you want something like this.  Can you explain more what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your solution was very helpful. Thanks a lot! Instead of decline.innerHTML = 'Accept'; I put decline.style.display = 'none' and that is what i've wanted.  Thank you again for helping me!

Comment: I'm happy this worked out 

Answer (score 0):

```js
const acceptRequest = document.getElementById('accept');
const declineRequest = document.getElementById('decline');
const actionsRequest = document.getElementsByClassName('action')[0]

acceptRequest.addEventListener('click', () => {
  actionsRequest.style.display = 'none';
  this.value = 'X accepted your request';
})
```

```html
<div class="request">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="profile-photo">
      <img src="Content/request1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Hajia Bintu</h5>
      <p class="text-muted">8 mutual friends</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="accept">Accept</button>
    <button class="btn" id="decline">Decline</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what you've done not just dump code in an answer and make the OP guess.

Comment: getElementsByClassName are htmlCollection when you try to access it you need the index number. Classes can be use for multiple times but id use once so you need to tell which class are you talking about. On which index number that class belongs to

Comment: const actionsRequest = document.getElementsByClassName('action')[0]  . I used [0] it means class on index 0 or you can simply say 1st class.

Comment: In the answer :)